# How can I reinstall my 14.04 Ubuntu from Windows 7

Tags: system-installation, software-installation

I updated my ubuntu from 13.10 to 14.04 but now it just gives me errors when I try to boot it saying it can't find the /. directory and it can't mount /tmp or some %$#@.

So I would really like to just uninstall it and install 14.04 again from scratch so I don't get random errors. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this vid here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=86KHkeBpsbA though it's for Ubuntu 12.04, the new ones aren't much different.